# question about idempotent operators

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $\dim(H)=\infty$. If each $T\in B(H)$ is finite sum of idempotent operators? If each $T\in B(H)$ is infinite sum of idempotent operators?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a *question*?